# Indexing data in OpenSearch from single DynamoDB table with multiple sort keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, full-text-search, opensearch

I have a single DynamoDB table which has data using the same partition key but different sort keys which stores different data structures based on the sort key. The structure of the table is similar shown below where different sort keys are used with the same partition key.

| id | type | customerId | items | additionalInfo | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cdd56430-5b57-4f2c-b831-5395db55d3cc | details | 1234 |  | some details |  |
| cdd56430-5b57-4f2c-b831-5395db55d3cc | inventory |  | [{"productId": 1, "count": 40}] |  | some details |
| afe92905-4b57-4e9d-9833-b77bd3c6e36f | details | 1234 |  | other details here |  |
| afe92905-4b57-4e9d-9833-b77bd3c6e36f | inventory |  | [{"productId": 2, "count": 100}] |  | some details |

I have a DynamoDB stream sending updates to a single OpenSearch index. Since these events use the same partition key, but different sort keys, each event will overwrite the data in the document stored in the index as the unique id for the document is only the partition key and not the sort key.

The goal is to index all data from this DynamoDB table into OpenSearch and be able to provide a plain text search for all data in the database.

In this scenario, would multiple indexes be used in OpenSearch and each index would be based on the sort key? If so, how would text searches be performed across multiple indexes and returned to the application?

Comment: I think you are using id data from your dynamo db, as _id in elasticsearch. You can store id as a separate key in the indexed document and let elastic generate _id for documents. In that way, your data with same id will not be over-written.

Comment: Thanks @CharchitKapoor. That's exactly what was happening. The partition key was being used as the _id of the document and overwriting the document when each item with a different sort key was updated. I was able to generate a UUID based on a string by concatenating the partition key and sort key (create_uuid_from_string in python). This allowed me to update the documents with different partition and sort keys and keeping all documents in one index.